# error: invalid conversion from `int (*)(int, ASN1_VALUE**, const ASN1_ITEM*)' to `int (*)(int, ASN1_VALUE**, const ASN1_ITEM*, void*)'?

Tags: c++, c, openssl

While upgrading OpenSSL I'm encountering these error like invalid conversion from

```
int (*)(int, ASN1_VALUE**, const ASN1_ITEM*)
```

to

```
int (*)(int, ASN1_VALUE**, const ASN1_ITEM*, void*)
```

Any one faced similar errors?

Comment: Seems you need to add a parameter. You'll have to read the documentation to learn what.

Comment: Looks like an extra argument was added to the signature. You'll have to modify the function you are assigning to it to also accept that argument. And odds are you won't have to worry about the value of it; the fact that it is void* suggests it is probably just some user-data type thing.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, Simply by adding one argument solved the problem.

Comment: What versions of OpenSSL?